# Как отсортировать таблицу INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT quiz.id,
       quiz.title,

       qcat.id `category_id`,
       qcat.title `category_title`,

       qcou.id `country_id`,
       qcou.title `country_title`,

       qopt.id `group_id`,
       qopt.title `group_title`,

       qtyp.id `type_id`,
       qtyp.title `type_title`,

       quse.id `user_id`,
       quse.login `user_name`,

       quiz.description,
       quiz.date_creation
FROM `quizzes` quiz
INNER JOIN `quiz_categories` qcat ON qcat.id = quiz.category_id
INNER JOIN `quiz_countries` qcou ON qcou.id = quiz.country_id
INNER JOIN `quiz_optgroup` qopt ON qopt.id = quiz.group_id
INNER JOIN `quiz_types` qtyp ON qtyp.id = quiz.type_id
INNER JOIN `users` quse ON quse.id = quiz.user_id
```

Подскажите как мне отсортировать таблицу по дате создания? (Недавно созданные итемы выше итемов которые созданы давно)

Comment: `order by колонка-с-датой desc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильное решение сортировка по дате создания

```
order by quiz.date_creation desc
```

Быстрое (временное) решение, или когда нет даты создания, то можно отсортировать по полю `ID`

```
order by quiz.id desc
```

Первичный ключ всегда прирастает и есть рекомендации, его никогда не изменять, так что в 99% случаев это будет работать.